# Struts 1 submit only works in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jsp, google-chrome, struts-1

I have some input fields that are created dynamically using JS. The thing is, when I submit the page, the setters of the Bean are not called, except when using IE. It only works on Chrome and Firefox when I add the input fields statically on the code.

This works on all browsers:

```
<input name="test" value="test"/>
```

This only works in IE:

```
var test = document.createElement('input');
test.name = 'test';
test.value = 'test';
tbody.appendChild(test);
```

Anyone know the solution, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my mistake. The `form` tag was inside my `table` tag.

Answer (score 1):

This guy had the same problem:

```
http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=518697&p=2742491
```

Try using html:rewrite to add new inputs.

Comment: Can you be more specific in how to use html:rewrite in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If that is a `tbody` element of a table as the variable name suggests, that is invalid markup. `tbody` can only have rows as a child.

Comment: <tbody> is inside a <table>. If I add the <input> directly in the code (inside <tbody>), it works fine. But adding them using JS only works on IE. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It works when you put it directly because the browser fixes your invalid code! Use the browsers console and inspect the html after it is rendered, look where the element is. You need to append it to a td which is inside of a tr which is inside of your tbody. Or just append it after the table.

Comment: Tried appending after table. Used this static code <input name="test" value="test"/> inside a td inside a tr. And tried inserting by JS again using this:   var TRtest = document.getElementById('TRtest');  
 var newTD = document.createElement('td');  
 var input = document.createElement('input');  
 input.name = 'test';  
 input.value = 'test';  
 newTD.appendChild(input);  
 TRteste.appendChild(newTD);. Same problem. Compared the html rendered and they appeared quite the same, except for the fact that on DOM inspection only the static one had an event listener on it. Thanks for you comment.